# Invertibility at any point $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following past exam question

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be given by $f(x,y) = (x^4 - y^4,xy)$
>
> (I) Evaluate the Jacobian of $f$, and its Jacobian determinant.
>
> (II) Show that $f$ is locally invertible at any point $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$
>
> (III) Is $f$ globally invertible on $\mathbb{R}^2 \backslash (0,0)$?

(I) I believe this is all they wanted: $ J = \left| \begin{align} & \frac{dx}{dx} && \frac{dx}{dy} \\ & \frac{dy}{dx} && \frac{dy}{dy} \end{align} \right| $

$ J = \left| \begin{align} & 4x^3 & -4y^3 \\ & y & x \end{align} \right| = 4x^4 + 4y^4$

(II) & (III), by Inverse function theorem :

If Jacobian matrix determinant is non-zero at $(x,y)$ then $f$ is invertible near $p=(x,y)$.
Hence $4x^4 + 4y^4=0$ only at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ so $f$ is invertible at all points but $(0,0)$

(III) Not sure how to show global invertibility. Will do further research and edit in my attempt.

Comment: I don't believe you are supposed to *find* the inverse relation, but rather use the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) to show that local inverses exist.

Comment: @Anorton This seems very likely. Thank you for that, I will update the question soon.

Comment: I am doing basically an identical question to this, could someone answer this one. I will bump it to the front.

Answer (score 1):

I think $f$ is not globally invertible because $f(-x,-y)=f(x,y)$.